# Why doesn't this while loop print anything on console?

Tags: java

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("12.23.45");
input.useDelimiter(".");
while ( input.hasNextInt() ) 
    System.out.println(input.nextInt());
```

Instead of printing 12, 23, 45 each in a new line, it does nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to escape `.`

```
Scanner input = new Scanner("12.23.45");
input.useDelimiter("\\.");
while (input.hasNextInt()) {
    System.out.println(input.nextInt());
}
```